# What are Xamarin player alternatives?

Tags: virtualization, virtualbox

It is possible to simulate Android using Xamarin player with Virtual Box:

[Mobile App Development & App Creation Software - Xamarin](https://xamarin.com/android-player)

The number of devices to choose is limited. Are there similar tools that are, like Xamarin player using Virtual Box (or a Virtual Box alternative).

Answer (score 0):

the best are [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/), [BlueStacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/), [Andy](http://www.andyroid.net/) and BlueStacks doesn't need Virtual Box. Genymotion is more suitable for developers